# Interview with head of department before technical interview

Tags: interviewing

What shall I expect? Head of department also has degree in same field but recruiter said that the interview is not technical. it will be after this interview

Comment: "*What shall I expect?*": questions? Like any interview?

Comment: Sorry, job interview specifically data analyst

Comment: A quick search will give you thousands of answers on how to prepare an interview, with questions, with so many fields covered...

Comment: Most likely they already know what to expect from you and first they check all the others.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect to be asked about your experience (at the general level of what you were involved in and what you liked or didn't like about it), , your interests, quite possibly what you find interesting about their company that caused you to apply, what you would like your career to include... all the soft-skills stuff that tells them who you are as a person and how well you'll fit into the company culture, independent of the precise set or level of technical skills you possess in any specific narrow topic. It can also be a good place to ask your own questions about what your career with the company might look like, what company educational benefits are available, and other non-technical questions of your own.